# REACT | Cannot post | mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-native

I'm working on making a forum and all has been fun until now, at least I thought so...
I got toe the register page and made all that BUT, as i send the post request from the page, it causes an error in the server

error:

```
(node:15264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: user.issModified is not a function
    at model.<anonymous> (D:\discussa\server\models\User.js:18:15)
    at callMiddlewareFunction (D:\discussa\server\node_modules\kareem\index.js:483:23)
    at model.next (D:\discussa\server\node_modules\kareem\index.js:58:7)
    at _next (D:\discussa\server\node_modules\kareem\index.js:107:10)
    at D:\discussa\server\node_modules\kareem\index.js:508:38
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:15264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:15264) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate 
the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

But also if I check the network in the developer tools on google, I see this `register  404 xhr content.js:6    420 B   61 ms`
I knew this isn't supposed to have a 404 err so if I click it, it obviously says `Cannot POST /auth/register`, but i cant figure out why.
I even get the 404 on every page like the home page.

I tried console logging my my path by doing this:

```js
var user = app.use('/api/user', require('./controllers/User'));
console.log(user)
```

Here is the output: https://pastebin.com/JnXRzSWM

At immediate though, I didn't think of this being of any use, but it has proven some sort of web page is trying to be pathed.

I checked the client and the server at least over 50 times and I cannot seem to understand the problem but I do know that it has something to do with some sort of misconfiguration with the server.

Here are the GitHub repos for the root directory and the client directory becuase they wouldn't go together in the same repo.

[root + server](https://github.com/bobrossrtx/Discussa-forum/tree/master/server)
[client](https://github.com/bobrossrtx/client/tree/main)

If you want the modules used to create the client, make sure your in the client directory then do:

```
npm install @testing-library/jest-dom @t@testing-library/user-event esting-library/react axios bcryptjs body-parser mongoose nodemon react react-dom react-router-dom react-scripts validator web-vitals
```

Or

```
yarn add @testing-library/jest-dom @t@testing-library/user-event esting-library/react axios bcryptjs body-parser mongoose nodemon react react-dom react-router-dom react-scripts validator web-vitals
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could do some testing and looking into it and could tell me what I have to do/fix

PS. If you do test it, make sure to add a database key in the .env file in the server directory

Answer (score 0):

Right, I'm going to just put this out there, I'm an idiot, I didn't read the error correctly and I didn't notice that I made a plain stupid error, 2 Simple Typos.
It is all fixed now.

FIX: server/models/User.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    createdAt: {
        defualt: Date.now(),
        type: Date
    },
    role: String,
});

UserSchema.pre( 'save', async function (next) {
    const user = this;
    if (!user.issModified('passwprd')) return next();
              ^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^
// Changed to if (!user.issModified('passwprd')) return next();

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
    user.password = hash;
    next()
});

const User = mongoose.model( 'User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```